# Java and OpenGL Hiding cube faces not seen

Tags: java, opengl, 3d

I have made a OpenGL 3D Render engine in Java that uses vbo's and such for optimization. Now I'm trying to take it further by hiding faces not seen by the user. I'm confused though, I have so far tried doing things like scan to see if blocks were adjacent. Then I decided whether to render or not. This is not working at all, the blocks don't even render now. Whats an efficient way of doing this, or does anyone know a good article to read up on?

Comment: This could be useful - [Face Culling](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Face_Culling)

Comment: How do you divide up the scene? What block are you referring to? IF the underlying scene structure allows for fast look-up of big scene chunks you can cull them when they are outside of view.

Comment: So far there is a 3d array that the blocks render on. In the render method it loops through the array and renders the blocks accordingly.